# How to get text in BS and add a tag around it

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have an XML-snippet that looks a little bit like this:

```
    <p> 
    lorem ipsum dolor <hi>a</hi>met. 
    Thing_A, <thing>Thing_B</thing>, Thing_C 
    </p>
```

The final structure should look sth. like this:

```
<p> lorem ipsum dolor <hi>a</met>. 
<thing>Thing_A</thing>, <thing>Thing_B</thing>, <thing>Thing_C</thing>
</p>
```

I figured I'll create a list like this

```
things = ['Thing_A', 'Thing_B', 'Thing_C']
```

and search for all things and surround them with a tag.
However, I couldn't find any info on doing that in the documentation. So I am searching for help :-D

Here is my code so far:

```
text = things[0]
print(text)
stelle = soup.find(text)
print(stelle)
tag = soup.new_tag('rs')
tag.append(text)
print(tag)
```

---

the output is:

Thing_A
None
Thing_A

I have played around a lot and not found a working solution ...

The output for my solution that is linked in comments with the weird -tag

```
    <body><tei xml:id="pa029" xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiheader>
<!-- The TEI-header from before-->
    </teiheader>
    <!--  <standOff/>-->
    <text>
    <pb n="29v"></pb>
    <p>
 {some content}
</p>
</text>
</tei>
</body>
```

when the correct way would be `<text><body>{some content} </body></text></tei>`

Has anyone any hints for me?
all the best,
K

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution, if I understood you correctly. I would go for a simple string replacement instead of doing the whole thing with the soup.

**Code**

```py
xml = """<p>
    lorem ipsum dolor <hi>a</hi>met.
    Thing_A, <thing>Thing_B</thing>, Thing_C
    </p>"""

things = ['Thing_A', 'Thing_B', 'Thing_C']

# Replicating the soup you already have 
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')

# Convert soup to string for replacement
new_xml = str(soup)

# To be specified
tag_start = '<thing>'
tag_end = '</thing>'

for thing in things:

    replacement_string = f"{tag_start}{thing}{tag_end}"
    new_xml = new_xml.replace(thing, replacement_string)

# drop potential created duplicates
new_xml = new_xml.replace(f"{tag_start}{tag_start}", tag_start)
new_xml = new_xml.replace(f"{tag_end}{tag_end}", tag_end)

# Create soup again
soup = BeautifulSoup(new_xml, 'lxml')
print(soup)
print(f"Type: {type(soup)}")
```

**Output**

```py
html><body><p>
    lorem ipsum dolor <hi>a</hi>met.
    <thing>Thing_A</thing>, <thing>Thing_B</thing>, <thing>Thing_C</thing>
</p></body></html>
Type: <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
```

Comment: I acme up with a working solution: https://pastebin.com/Zyx5wEia
(I am actualy talking about ships here I missed making it generic :-D ) 
Our solutions have the same problem: they move the <body> tag for whole documents around the result. (That would be an issue :-D )

Comment: Can you make an example for "move the <body> tag for whole documents around the result"?

Comment: added it to the top

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75880413/beautifulsoup-puts-body-tag-around-xml-document 
maybe better talk about it here, since technically u answered the question :-D

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how efficient it would be, but you could just loop through `things`, split strings containing a substring from `things` and use [`.insert...`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) like:

```py
xStr = '    <p>\n    lorem ipsum dolor <hi>a</hi>met.\n    Thing_A, <thing>Thing_B</thing>, Thing_C\n    </p>' 

thing_tag = 'thing' # 'rs' # 
things = ['Thing_A', 'Thing_B', 'Thing_C']

p_snip = BeautifulSoup(xStr, 'lxml').p
```

```py
def wrap_str(s, name='rs', attrs=None): 
    if not isinstance(attrs, dict): 
        attrs = {'type':"org", 'ref':f"#{s.lower()}"}
    wrapped = BeautifulSoup(f'<{name}>{s}</{name}>', 'lxml').find(name)
    for k,v in attrs.items(): wrapped[k] = v
    return wrapped

for thing in things:
    thing_strs = [
        d for d in soup.descendants if isinstance(d,str) and not d.PREFIX
        and thing in d and not (d.strip()==thing and d.parent.name==thing_tag)
    ]
    for thing_str in thing_strs:
        for si, str_sect in enumerate(thing_str.split(thing)):
            # if si: thing_str.insert_before(wrap_str(thing, thing_tag)) 
            if si: thing_str.insert_before(wrap_str(thing, thing_tag, {})) 
            thing_str.insert_before(str_sect)
        thing_str.replace_with('')
```

and after that, `p_snip` should look like your desired output:

> ```html
>     <p> 
>     lorem ipsum dolor <hi>a</hi>met. 
>     <thing>Thing_A</thing>, <thing>Thing_B</thing>, <thing>Thing_C</thing> 
>     </p>
> ```

although, if you use `wrap_str` with the default `attrs` parameter like in the commented *`if si...`* line and with `thing_tag='rs'`, then `p_snip` should look like:

> ```html
>     <p> 
>     lorem ipsum dolor <hi>a</hi>met. 
>     <rs ref="#thing_a" type="org">Thing_A</rs>, <thing><rs ref="#thing_b" type="org">Thing_B</rs></thing>, <rs ref="#thing_c" type="org">Thing_C</rs> 
>     </p>
> ```