# beautifulSoup puts body tag around xml document

Tags: beautifulsoup

Good evening,

The following function should return a TEI-conform document that includes {lowered_word} inside of , which it does.
Oddly enough, it moves the body tag to a weird place. It wrapes the whole document with the body-tag and puts the  where it belongs.It is weird. Can anybody help with that? :-D

```
def choice_reg(text):
    with open(f"{text}.xml", "r") as f:
        file = f.read()

    soup = bs(file, 'lxml')
    soup2 = soup.find("TEI", recursive=True)
    no_reg = [el for el in soup2.find_all('choice') if not el.find('reg') if not el.find('abbr')]
    test = no_reg
    soon_reg = test
    for choice in soon_reg:
        orig = choice.find('orig')
        reg_string = orig.getText().lower()
        new_reg = soup2.new_tag('reg')
        new_reg.string = reg_string
        orig.insert_after(new_reg)
    print(soup2)

    with open(f"{text.split('.')[0]}2.xml", "w") as f:
        file = f.write(str(soup2))
```

the following is an example piece of my XML.

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="pa029">
  <teiHeader>
    <fileDesc>
      <titleStmt>
        <title/>
        <author>Kevin Wunsch</author>
      </titleStmt>
      <editionStmt>
        <edition>
          <date>2018-04-25</date>
        </edition>
      </editionStmt>
      <publicationStmt>
        <p></p>
      </publicationStmt>
      <sourceDesc>
        <p>Add a wonderful description of the transcription process as well as the physical appearance of the book</p>
      </sourceDesc>
    </fileDesc>
    <encodingDesc>
      <p>it is encoded</p>
    </encodingDesc>
    <!-- replace the above with a function to grab header from header.xml  -->
    <revisionDesc>
      <listChange>
        <change>
          <date>2019-06-30T16:37:03Z</date>
          <name></name>
        </change>
      </listChange>
    </revisionDesc>
  </teiHeader>
<!--  <standOff>-->
<!--    <listPlace>
      <place xml:id="p001-juanfernandez">
        <placeName>Juan Fernandez</placeName>
        <location>
          <geo>-33.666667, -78.833333</geo>
        </location>
      </place>
      <place xml:id="p002-stcatherines">
        <placeName>
          <orig>St. Catherines</orig>
          <reg>St. Catherine's</reg>
        </placeName>
        <location>
          <geo>test-testitest-test</geo>
        </location>
      </place>
    </listPlace>
  </standOff>-->
  <text>
    <body>
      <pb n="29v"></pb>
      <p>
      <rs ref="#centurion" type="org">Centurion</rs> <rs ref="#p001-juanfernandez" type="place">Juan Fernandez</rs> <date when="1741-07-01">July 1<hi rend="superscript">st</hi> 1741</date>
      <lb/>Sir,
      <lb/>By the report of <choice><orig>Provisions</orig></choice> belonging to his <choice><abbr>Maj<hi rend="superscript">ts</hi></abbr><expan>Majesties'</expan></choice> <choice><orig>Ship</orig></choice> <rs ref="#centurion" type="org">Centurion</rs> at <rs ref="#p002-stcatherine" type="place">St. Catherines</rs>
      <lb/>
</p>
</body>
</text>
</TEI>
```

Comment: Part of it is down to the parser - what if you try parsing as `xml` instead of `lxml` (*`soup=bs(file,'xml')`*)

Comment: still moves the <body> - tag :-D 
It' just for data-cleaning and nothing too important, I can work with my solution, for now :-D

Comment: really? [this is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF3S2.png) after parsing as `xml` - it looks the same to me but maybe I'm missing something...or does it behave differently for you?

Comment: interesting ... maybe we have varying versions of some tool :-D 
(Tumbleweed, Python 3.10 rest I'd have to check) :-D

Answer (score 0):

As a circumvention of this issue, and I have no idea, whether there is a better way to do this, so feel free to correct me:

```
def choice_reg(text):
    with open(f"{text}.xml", "r") as f:
        file = f.read().replace("<body>", "<mybody>").replace("</body>", "</mybody>")

    soup = bs(file, 'lxml')
    no_reg = [el for el in soup.find_all('choice') if not el.find('reg') if not el.find('abbr')]
    print(no_reg)
    test = no_reg
    soon_reg = test
    for choice in soon_reg:
        orig = choice.find('orig')
        reg_string = orig.getText().lower()
        new_reg = soup.new_tag('reg')
        new_reg.string = reg_string
        orig.insert_after(new_reg)
    print(soup)

    with open(f"{text.split('.')[0]}2.xml", "w") as f:
        file = f.write(str(soup).replace("<html><body>", "").replace("</body></html>", "").replace("<mybody>", "<body>").replace("</mybody>", "</body>"))
```